# Chrome Extension - Can't change back to default icon after chrome.browserAction.setIcon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm trying to toggle my extension on and off. During this time, the icon should change from colored to grey, and then back to colored after turning it back on. It works fine when it changes from colored to grey, and then returns errors after attempting to turn it back:

```
Could not load action icon '/images/non-grey/icon16.png'.
Could not load action icon '/images/non-grey/icon32.png'.
Could not load action icon '/images/non-grey/icon48.png'.
Could not load action icon '/images/non-grey/icon128.png'.
```

This is the code:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request.action);
  if (enabled) {
    if (request.action == "check-window") {
      let querying = chrome.tabs.query({
        title: "ImageSafetyBackgroundProcess",               
    }, function(array_of_Tabs) {
        if (array_of_Tabs.length == 0) {
          window.open("popup.html", "popup");
        }
      });
    }
  }
  if (request.action == "enable-disable") {
    if (enabled) {
      enabled = false;
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: {
        16: "/images/grey/greyedicon16.png",
        32: "/images/grey/greyedicon32.png",
        48: "/images/grey/greyedicon48.png",
        128: "/images/grey/greyedicon128.png"
      }});
      let querying = chrome.tabs.query({
        title: "ImageSafetyBackgroundProcess",               
        }, function(array_of_Tabs) {
        if (array_of_Tabs.length > 0) {
          chrome.tabs.remove(array_of_Tabs[0].id, function() { });
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      enabled = true;
      window.open("popup.html", "popup");
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: {
        16: "/images/non-grey/icon16.png",
        32: "/images/non-grey/icon32.png",
        48: "/images/non-grey/icon48.png",
        128: "/images/non-grey/icon128.png"
      }});
    }
  } });
```

Manifest.json:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Borderify",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Adds a red border to all webpages matching mozilla.org.",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/question.png"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "downloads",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "button.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/icon16.png",
      "32": "/images/icon32.png",
      "48": "/images/icon48.png",
      "128": "/images/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content-script.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "main.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the path is incorrect.

Comment: @wOxxOm I made the second set of images the default in manifest.json, and it worked fine. The paths are correct.

Comment: Well then it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: if I make it another image it still doesn't work. Could still be a bug I suppose.

Comment: Try re-saving the image in another graphics editor.

Comment: Hi there, What Chrome version do you use? There is a public bug report that said this issue should be fixed in Chrome v100.0.4894.0. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1262029&q=chrome.action.setIcon&can=1

Comment: I found the problem. I have web request blocking and it blocked the image from loading. Sorry, there was no way anyone would have known that.

Answer (score 1):

use this code in `background.js` so that the icon will be change when refresh

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'loading') {
      chrome.action.setIcon({ path: 'images/icon-32.png' });
    }
  });
```